# Simple TCP Client-Server application throws exception

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

My TCP Server

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);
    System.out.println("Server started");
    while (true) {
      Socket socket = server.accept();
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      System.out.println("Received: " + input.readLine() + "\n");
    }
  }
```

My TCP Client.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      outToServer.writeBytes(i + "\n");
      clientSocket.close();
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
```

The loop in TCP client runs till 16374 and stopped, throwing this exception.

```
...
...
...
16372
16373
16374
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at mawia.test.Client.main(Test.java:11)
```

1. What is wrong with my code?
2. Why do I get this error?
3. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need to remove Socket socket = server.accept(); this line out of loop. It is creating connections every time the loop iterates.

Comment: @SaurabhJinturkar That is on purpose. Look at the Client: It starts a new connection in each loop. Moving the `accept` out of the loop in the server would result in an error.

Comment: @Mawia I guess you are creating too many connections in too short time. Try adding a sleep in your client's loop and see what happens.

Comment: Mawia: Can you please elaborate, what you are trying to achieve? Is this some sort of "proof-of-concept"? If you have to put a high load on the server, you maybe better use more Clients with lower freqency each.

Comment: @Fildor I have an application that receives TCP messages. I want to sent thousands of messages at once but it throws the same exception like this simple TCP Client-Server application I posted. I need to write the client in such a way that it should not throw the above error.

Comment: Then you really should use one connection per client not per message. Have a look at harsh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fildor is right, you are creating too many connections or `Socket handles`, this internally translates to allowed `open-file-handles` per process which in most probability you are breaking.

Ideal approach would be for client to keep on sending data (`50000 records`) on one connections i.e. `Socket` and `Server` should handle processing this data in a separate thread (So you can run multiple TCP Client concurrently):

**TCP Server**

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);
        System.out.println("Server started");
        while (true) {
          final Socket socket = server.accept();
          Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Server received message from client: ");
                BufferedReader input;
                try {
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    while(!socket.isClosed() && socket.getInputStream().available() > 0){
                        System.out.println("Received: " + input.readLine() + "\n");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Client disconnected from server");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //break;
                }
            }
        });
          t.start();
        }
      }
```

**TCP Client**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
        for (int i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.writeBytes(i + "\n");
            outToServer.flush();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
```

Comment: Mawia's approach looks to me like a "proof-of-concept". Maybe he will be urged to handle many very short-lived-connections transferring minimal data. But as long as we do not know, I consider this a good proposal.

Comment: Just one thing: `available()` - I cannot recommend its usage. Bad experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Also try once with adding `flush()` in your TCP Client code before closing the connection, worked with me.